# Clone a two-factor authentication enabled private GitHub repo from Azure Pipeline template with a PAT as a secret

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to clone a 2FA enabled private GitHub repo to my azure pipeline. My configuration is as follows.

```
trigger: none

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - azure

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo "--------------- Clone 2FA enabled private repo ---------------"
    git clone https://github-azure-pipeline-user:$(PAT)@github.com/parent-org/2fa-enabled-github-repo.git
    echo "--------------- Clone Completed ---------------"
  displayName: 'Clone 2FA enabled private repo'
```

Personal access token(PAT) for `github-azure-pipeline-user` is configured as a variable from the Azure DevOps UI. The issue is when the type of the variable `PAT` is changed to `secret` from the UI, the git clone does not work. Authentication failed error is displayed.

```
--------------- Clone 2FA enabled private repo ---------------
Cloning into '2fa-enabled-github-repo'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/parent-org/2fa-enabled-github-repo.git/'
--------------- Clone Completed ---------------
```

When `PAT` is set as a plain text variable, this works without an issue.

Is this a bug in Azure pipelines or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables):

> Secret variables are encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key.
> Secrets are available on the agent for tasks and scripts to use. Be
> careful about who has access to alter your pipeline.
>
> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into
> environment variables for scripts. You need to explicitly map secret
> variables.

So you may try the following syntax:

```
- script: |
    echo "--------------- Clone 2FA enabled private repo ---------------"
    git clone https://github-azure-pipeline-user:$env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR@github.com/parent-org/2fa-enabled-github-repo.git
    echo "--------------- Clone Completed ---------------"
  displayName: 'Clone 2FA enabled private repo'
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(PAT)
```